# How to update a Kentico Aspx Template Page?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I created a template page, and a page that uses that template in Kentico. So I edited the aspx template file, but the changes arent being updated when viewing the page in the CMS. I turned off caching and everything, but I cannot get my changes viewable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use web application (there are .designer.cs files in your solution) you have to rebuild the app. Or you can try changing Codebehind to CodeFile in your aspx markup.(Not really clean method but will ensure file gets build dynamically as they do under web site).

If you use web site and you tried to delete cache (CMS Site Manager->Administration->System->Clear cache) you are doing something wrong, believe me.

As a last resort you can try to clear asp.net temporary files
(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\your version\Temporary ASP.NET Files). This will need IIS to be restarted.

Differences between web app. and web site are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).